# Kubernetes podAffinity

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to get some pods to co-locate with their data stores, but the affinity rules don't seem to be playing ball.

The rules I have in place for search-one, are:

```
    podAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values:
              - solr
          namespaces:
          - search-one
          - search-solr
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        weight: 75
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app
              operator: In
              values:
              - search-one
          topologyKey: failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone
        weight: 50
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: app
            operator: In
            values:
            - search-one
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

What this is trying to express is "Prefer to run on the same node as search-solr, ideally in different zones, and never run two instances of search-one on the same node"

But as you can see, only one of the `search-one` instances co-locater with a solr.

```
❯ k get pods --all-namespaces -o wide -l app=search-one
NAMESPACE    NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
search-one   search-one-76f6cdbc6b-dwjjq   2/2       Running   0          1h        10.202.3.19   gke-delivery-platform-custom-pool-698c2edf-jdrp
search-one   search-one-76f6cdbc6b-xg89n   2/2       Running   0          1h        10.202.5.42   gke-delivery-platform-custom-pool-705aff48-phhr

❯ k get pods --all-namespaces -o wide -l app=solr
NAMESPACE     NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP            NODE
search-solr   solr-0    2/2       Running   0          13h       10.202.1.11   gke-delivery-platform-custom-pool-705aff48-g73b
search-solr   solr-1    2/2       Running   0          11h       10.202.9.6    gke-delivery-platform-custom-pool-ef7d431d-gwxz
search-solr   solr-2    2/2       Running   1          20h       10.202.3.10   gke-delivery-platform-custom-pool-698c2edf-jdrp
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe it's in the same zone and that's why not scheduling? sure that the real conditions meet your definition?

Comment: You can also use Taints and Tolerations on the nodes [https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/]. It works the opposite of pod affinity where it will repel pods from being assigned to nodes.

Comment: Jason, I don't think taints and tolerations help me or hinder me here.

@DavidSteiman which is in the same zone?  Solr is spread across 3 zones, 705aff48, ef7d431d and 698c2edf.  search-one is also spread across 2.  Therefore the zonal preferred anti affinity is working, as it the required node anti affinity,  but i can't see any logical reason why search-one-76f6cdbc6b-xg89n wouldn't be scheduled with solr-0

Comment: Are you deploying both pods with the same file or deploying each one seperately? If you are deploying them at the same time which one is being deployed first? Also, if you delete the pod that is not being scheduled properly, does it reschedule properly later?